How do I stop frozen Chinese dumplings from sticking to the pot when boiling them?
I frequently cook frozen Chinese dumplings (餃子 jiǎozi) as a quick meal using the instructions on the pack: boil a pot of water, add frozen dumplings, bring pot back to boiling on high heat, turn down to a simmer and allow to cook for X minutes. Simple enough and most dumplings turn out just fine.
However, inevitably some dumplings stick to the bottom of the pot, which breaks them apart and is a pain to clean up afterwards.  How can I stop this from happening?
And yes, I know I could also pan-fry or steam them, but that's a different story.  Also note that unlike some other dumplings, jiaozi are usually heavier than water when frozen, so they sink to the bottom at first and only rise up to the top when cooked.

Gently stir (continuously) until they are floating so they can't sit on the bottom and stick. Tedious, but very effective.
Use a pasta insert or a folding steamer basket inside the pot (full of boiling water, you said you didn't want to steam them) so there's a layer of water between the actual bottom of the pot and where the dumplings come to rest.

Additionally the sticking should be less if you wait until the water is vigorously boiling and use a big pot relative to the quantity of dumplings, so the water will get back to vigorously boiling quickly after you throw in the frozen dumplings.
